# Who voted who on every round?

Tags: circle

In the movie [Circle](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3118452/) I had the sense that the votes didn't add up or make much sense, especially in the beginning where there are more people in the circle.

Is there any data about who voted for who on every round?

Comment: I haven't seen the film so I have no clue but based on the description on IMDb, it sounds like they weren't even aware of the "voting" at the beginning, so I don't know that there's any way to actually answer this. "*At first the attacks seem random, but, soon the strangers realize that they, as a group, have the power to decide who will be the next to be killed: by the power of the vote.*"

Comment: @Catija the film is quite good and I suspect there was much thought put on it, so I hope that the writer(s) may have put real votes in the background, I couldn't find any data so far though :(

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the movie three times in which I could pause and rewind.

No.  There is no way to determine each person's vote (whether they knew they were voting or not); particularly in the earlier rounds.  Remember, if one votes in the minority; that result is ignored.

Comment: Sometimes the votes seemed impossible (or improbable), especially in the ties.